# How to have these buttons clicked automatically at an interval jquery

Tags: jquery

```
    <button class="siteButton bigButton" onclick="setCategory('123456');"><span>save</span></button>
<button class="siteButton bigButton" onclick="setCategory('123455');"><span>save</span></button>
<button class="siteButton bigButton" onclick="setCategory('123454');"><span>save</span></button>
<button class="siteButton bigButton" onclick="setCategory('123453');"><span>save</span></button>
```

How do i click on the save button using jquery after an interval maybe of 0.5 seconds

Comment: Can you explain further? Interval or delay?

Comment: delay between consecutive clicks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this using `setInterval()`

```js
var buttons = $('.siteButton');
var len = buttons.length,
  i = 0;

var interv = setInterval(function() {
  buttons.eq(i++).click();
  if (i == len)
    clearInterval(interv);
},1000);


function setCategory(v) {
  alert(v);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="siteButton bigButton" onclick="setCategory('123456');"><span>save</span>
</button>
<button class="siteButton bigButton" onclick="setCategory('123455');"><span>save</span>
</button>
<button class="siteButton bigButton" onclick="setCategory('123454');"><span>save</span>
</button>
<button class="siteButton bigButton" onclick="setCategory('123453');"><span>save</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `seTimeout` for doing that:

```
function setCategory(value)
{
    setTimeout(function(){
       //do anything here
    }, 500)
}
```

When you click a button, everything inside setTimeout function will be run after 0.5 seconds.

Comment: the id's are varying, how do i achieve it with the html above?

Comment: Not depends on ids, just put that function inside a `<script></script>` tag in the `head` section of the page.

Comment: apparently its for a tampermonkey script and the site is not mine.. Can the buttons be triggered using the class?